# My application stops writing to files and opening new TCP connections after some time

Tags: node.js

I have no idea what could be causing this.

I have a Node application which connects to an external server over TCP and communicates with it. Part of its functionality also includes making relatively frequent HTTP requests.

Each instance of the application establishes up to 30 TCP connections to the external server, and makes HTTP requests as needed. Previously, I've been hosting the application on relatively cheap VPSes, with one instance of the application per server.

Now I'm setting it up on a proper dedicated server. I *could* set it up to run one instance on the dedicated and increase the connection limit that I've set so that one instance could cover several smaller instances on the VPSes, but I'd rather set up several instances of the application on the dedicated each limited to 30 connections.

The application also writes logs to disk (just a plain flat file), and sends logs via UDP to an external logging server. This is done using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston).

After some uptime, however, I'm experiencing an issue where HTTP requests time out (ETIMEDOUT) and the logs stop being written to disk. The application itself is still running, and the TCP connection to the server is still active and working. I can communicate with the application through that connection and it responds as expected. The logging server is still receiving the UDP packets as well. I've noticed that the log files stop being written to, but after a few minutes they appear to be flushed to disk finally, and the missed logs then appear.

My first suspicion was an open-files limit being hit, but the OS (Ubuntu) doesn't have a limit that I'm hitting. I tried disabling any Node HTTP Agent behavior (I'm using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, so I just passed `false` for the `agent` option).

It's not the webserver on the other end rejecting my connections. While the issue was occurring I was able to successfully `wget` a file from the webserver using the same external IP as the Node app is using.

I'm tailing the log file and noticing that the time between when a line is generated and when it's flushed to the disk is gradually increasing.

CPU and memory usage are low so there's no way that's the issue. iowait in `top` is `0.0`. I have no idea where to go from here. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

I have Node 5.10.1.

Comment: I upgraded the server from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 15 and the issue resolved itself. No idea what the underlying problem was.